# Disable My SQL Foreign Key Constrain (FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS ) from bat file

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I need to run around 100 .sql files from a batch file for loading data into a look up table in our application. I need to disable constains before loading process starts and enable it again after the process finish.

My current code is

```
    for /r "%ScriptsPathLookup%" %%f in (*.sql) do ( 
mysql --host=%Server% --port=%PortNumber% --user=%UserName% --password=%UserPassword% --database=%DB% <%ConstrainPath%\Constrain-disable.sql<%%f)

Here Constrain-disable.sql -> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

But this is not working. I believe if I go and put 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;' in all the .sql files it will load correctly. This is not the best approach and would be tough to maintain. Can anyone suggest a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code has double input redirects `<` which isn't going to work.  A relatively simple approach, using the same looping mechanism that you have, involves creating a temporary file with the *disable* code at the top and then using that file with the MySQL command.

```
set TempFile="%TEMP%\MyTempSql.sql"
for /r "%ScriptsPathLookup%" %%f in (*.sql) do (
  type %ConstrainPath%\Constrain-disable.sql >%TempFile%
  echo.>>%TempFile%
  type %%f >>%TempFile%
  mysql --host=%Server% --port=%PortNumber% --user=%UserName% --password=%UserPassword% --database=%DB% <%TempFile%
)
del %TempFile%
```